# Another thread removed element from queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have multiple threads using shared variabled `queue`. After processing it (printing) it removes the element from the queue

```
protected void tryToPrint() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (printer.isAvailable() && printer.isFair(this)) {
                queueLock.lock();
                try {
                    if (queue.isEmpty()) 
                        break;

                    printer.requestToPrint(this, queue.get(0));
                    queue.remove(0);
                    synchronized (System.out) {
                        System.out.println(getName() + " printed. queue size: " + queue.size());
                    }
                } finally {
                    queueLock.unlock();
                }
            } else {
                printer.requestToPrintNext(this);
            }
        } catch (IllegalPrintStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:445)
    at printer.ClientImpl.tryToPrint(ClientImpl.java:34)
    at printer.AbstractClient.run(AbstractClient.java:28)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I suppose another thread somehow removed an element from the queue? How is that possible I throught I locked it?

**UPDATE**: queue is actually a `ArrayList<File>()`. Does it matter if its not thread safe? I did lock the `queueLock`?

Comment: What is the type of `queue`?

Comment: @CyrilleKa, its an `ArrayList<File>()`

Comment: Can you post code for what other threads might do to the queue?  Is it possible that one of them is not honoring `queueLock`?

Comment: Tell me about queueLock - what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your specific example, what is queueLock? Where is it created? Is it shared between threads (e.g. static - my guess is no, which could be causing your problems)? Need more info.

If you don't want to worry about all those questions, then just rewrite it using synchronized. Simpler ...

```
protected void tryToPrint() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (printer.isAvailable() && printer.isFair(this)) {
                synchronized(queue) {
                    if (queue.isEmpty()) 
                        break;

                    printer.requestToPrint(this, queue.get(0));
                    queue.remove(0);
                    synchronized (System.out) {
                        System.out.println(getName() + " printed. queue size: " + queue.size());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                printer.requestToPrintNext(this);
            }
        } catch (IllegalPrintStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: QueueLock is a `ReentrantLock(true)`. I think the the error is because its not `static`. After defining it as static, should it be the same as `synchronized(queue)`? I don't seem to get the same result ... the setup is 3 client threads running this code. 1 printer (server) thread acting as a print server.

Comment: Somehow it seems like `printer.requestToPrint(this, queue.get(0));` is ran multiple times before the system.out prints the queue size thing. How is that possible. It seems to be possible (tho less likely with `synchronized(queue)`). This is the only code that runs for client. Server does not access the queue in any way. Code is at http://pastie.org/6438147. Note that I only modified the `*Impl.java` files the rest are from lecturer thus assumed working. Its more of an interface.

Comment: If using queueLock and it is not declared static then it's definitely a problem, since each thread would lock it's own queueLock.

Comment: `synchronized(queue)` guarantees exlcusive access on the queue object. So any weirdness (if it still exists) must be somewhere else, like in the print methods. By the look of it though, synchronized should solve the problem.